# ABP.io cancel background job when application is stopped

Tags: abp

In the Abp Framework (ABP.IO, Version: 5.2.1)

I need a way to **cancel**/stop a very **long-running background workers/jobs** when the **application is stopped**.

**Currently**, background workers/jobs **continue running** and **prevent the application** from **stopping**.
example log output:

```
10 May 2022 13:52:29.311 Parsing ended for a cdr file: 'xxx' in '122' seconds
10 May 2022 13:52:19.874 Parsing ended for a cdr file: 'xxx' in '113' seconds
10 May 2022 13:52:18.093 Parsing file 'xxx'
10 May 2022 13:52:17.969 Parsing started for a cdr file: 'xxx'
10 May 2022 13:52:07.572 Parsing ended for a cdr file: 'xxx' in '100' seconds

10 May 2022 13:52:06.959 Application is shutting down...

10 May 2022 13:51:36.174 Parsing file 'xxx'
10 May 2022 13:51:36.072 Parsing started for a cdr file: 'xxx'
10 May 2022 13:51:29.453 Parsing ended for a cdr file: 'xxx' in '62' seconds
10 May 2022 13:50:56.258 Parsing file 'xxx'
10 May 2022 13:50:56.223 Parsing started for a cdr file: 'xxx'
10 May 2022 13:50:52.202 Parsing ended for a cdr file: 'xxx' in '25' seconds
```

I have tried **injecting** an `ICancellationTokenProvider`, but it **didn't help**.

```cs
await GetFilesList().ParallelForEachAsync(async file =>
{
    // Do some parsing
}, _cancellationTokenProvider.Token);
```

Comment: 1. Where do you **create** the cancellation token? 2. Where do you **handle** the cancellation token? (You only showed where you **pass** the cancellation token.)

Comment: @aaron this is an Abp Framework application, `CancellationTokenProvider` is handled by the framework itself: [See docs](https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Cancellation-Token-Provider)

Comment: Since you're not in a web request, that's probably `null`.